# Android gradle Dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to add gradle dependency dynamically based on certain configuration file 
that tells android studio what libraries to be added to the project

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you just not add all  the dependency ? also you are asking if you will make it dynamically in code ?

Comment: So the size of app will not grow so much also it will be used by more than  one team so each team will use its configuration file that will add these libraries alongside the required code needed by  this dependency

Comment: You cannot do that , when you finish your app and you want to publish it online , all the library and code will be in the same package .apk , you cannot add an external library

Comment: @mrx10, I'm agree with ArolaAb. dynamic gradle dependency can't be configured since AAPT tools add all dependency while packaging an application for publishing or debugging.

Comment: What is the criteria for choosing what dependency to include? If it is product flavor or build type it is simple. If something other than that elaborate your question with a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like:

- build.gradle that contains "standard" configuration, common and shared across all teams
- some special configurations (but for the same project) which can vary from team to team

And you want to avoid, that you have to check out or comment some dependencies all the time, just because the last checkin was from Team B, and Team A needs some other dependencies (or different versions of the same dependencies).

Am I right so far?

This can be done with a new flag in gradle, called `apply-from`.
More or less, this is an `include` command, which allows you to import the content of a seperate file into your current build.gradle config.

I use this for my projects to include the signing config (it exists only once for all my apps and is just "included" in the builds, and not copied over and over again).
Same for some standard dependencies, like support library, espresso and similar things.
This keeps your build.gradle file small.

Look at this example from my build-files, I think you can adapt it for your use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../../stdcfg/app/default.build.gradle'
apply from: '../../stdcfg/app/include.libs.gradle'
apply from: '../../stdcfg/app/signingconfig.gradle'

android {
    // ... normal contents of your build file
}
```

The `apply-from` includes any file to this build.gradle file. As an example, here's the (partial) contents of my default.build.gradle file and you see, this can even add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
}
```

So, how can you adapt that for your use?

Say, Team A and Team B each get one specific file, we name the file `teamconfig.gradle`.
In Team A's branch, the file contains the config for Team A, in Team B's branch for team B.
Both teams use the same build.gradle file for their app, which contains this line:

```
apply from: '../branches/teamconfig/teamconfig.gradle'
```

And this file contains the team-specific config.

Hope this helps.